# data from database is not inserted into my webpage properly

Tags: javascript, html

i have created a webpage in which data is being inserted in html document using javascript and ajax. I used to display the words like **don't it's**
But when these words are inserted in html div, they are like **don�t it�s**.
Anybody please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Show the code that result's in such improper behavior then only people would be able to answer here.

Comment: Looks like maybe an encoding issue

Comment: it looks like a similar question has been asked on SO before:


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086717/why-do-symbols-like-apostrophes-and-hyphens-get-replaced-with-black-diamonds-on

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"> or use <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
found a link on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following articles will be useful

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

After you connect to the database issue the following command:

SET NAMES 'utf8';

Ensure that your web page also uses the UTF-8 encoding:

PHP also offers several function that will be useful for conversions:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

http://us.php.net/mb_convert_encoding