# getting � from a string after parsing

Tags: php, regex, string

I am parsing a string like any other string, or apparently it is
I am still getting `�` instead of some white spaces
the parser is working with all other strings but this

the original string is :

```
CONTENT content CONTENT content CONTENT content CONTENT
```

I am getting :

```
CONTENT content�CONTENT content�CONTENT content�
```

I did filter the output from `/r/n /n` and HTML characters , and as I mentioned , it works with every other string and html characters

do you have any reasons for that ? I tried to encode the output , but nothing changed , but when I decode it  , it disappears along with all the string

code :

```
    $posts_info[$counter][2] = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i","",$posts_info[$counter][2]);
    $posts_info[$counter][2] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $posts_info[$counter][2]);
    $n_lines = explode("\n",   $posts_info[$counter][2]);
    $new_lines = array();

    foreach ($n_lines as $i => $line) {
        if(!empty($line))
            $new_lines[] = trim($line);
    }

    $posts_info[$counter][2] =    implode($new_lines);
```

Comment: What are you viewing the text with?  A document editor, command line, web browser, etc?  What are you using to parse the strings?

Comment: what language you parsing with?

Comment: I am using PHP , and viewing the text with Chrome , I will add the code that filters the output now , please note that I didn't have to add filters before I face this problem with that string

Comment: What is your document encoding type/charset?

Answer (score 0):

After you connect to the database add the following command:

`SET NAMES 'utf8';`

Ensure that your web page also uses the **UTF-8** encoding

Also check this link, it might be useful..
[data from database is not inserted into my webpage properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688745/data-from-database-is-not-inserted-into-my-webpage-properly)