# Not able to remove "—" from string which is failing string comparison

Tags: java, testng

I am performing string comparison in selenium automation.
For a field, I am getting this value from UI:

Actual Value: Institutional Investors & Consultants — Canada

And same value, I have stored as a String expected value in my test.

Expected Value: Institutional Investors & Consultants — Canada

When I perform, testng assertEqual method to this, this is failing with this error message:

```
Actual Result : Institutional Investors & Consultants — Canada 
Expected Result : Institutional Investors & Consultants â€” Canada
```

I tried to remove these special character with:

```
replaceAll("â€", "-")
```

but failed with the same message.

Try setting the encoding in the constructor of string:

```
subject = new String(subject.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

This also didn't work.

I have apache common lang3 and jsoup also. If anyone knows any good method from there to tackle this, let me know, as first I want to avoid regex and use standard libraries.

Code:

```
if(loc contains ("Canada")) {
 Assert.assertEquals("somelocator.getText().trim()", "ExpectedValue");
}
```

Moreover, just simple println is prining as:

Institutional Investors & Consultants â€” Canada for Institutional Investors & Consultants — Canada.

When I print it in different console, then it prints fine.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38148083/16688813) will help

Comment: Have tried this, this also didn't work

Comment: Maybe you are using a different hyphen? https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/punctuation/3-types-of-dashes-and-correct-usage-in-writing.html  . Well, its just a guess

Comment: I copy pasted the actual value, so it's same.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your second code snippet probably failed because as it seems you forgot to include the ” sign in the repaceAll call: [Here](https://digwp.com/2011/07/clean-up-weird-characters-in-database/) you see that there are different possibilities:

```
replaceAll('â€”', '—') 
replaceAll('â€“', '–')
replaceAll('â€¢', '-')
```

Different length hyphens have different encodings and therefore won't compare as equal.

Comment: Thanks for this. It might help someone. But It wouldn't work if your file encoding is set differently at global level.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just thought I have to mention this as this approach was one you used while trying to figure out your current issues

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed in IDE (Intelij)->

1. ctrl+alt+s (Setting) -> Editor-> File Encoding -> Change file encoding to UTF-8. By default , it is set to windows-1252

It need to change for files individually as well from there.

2. The same issue was coming in Jenkin (windows) machine also. It got fixed by:
   adding encoding in pom.xml file at 3 places mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368527/is-there-a-way-to-make-maven-build-class-files-with-utf-8-without-using-the-exte/10375505#10375505).